# How to delete SOLR indexed data by query with curl?

Tags: curl, solr, schema, http-delete

I have a SOLR schema.xml like this:

```xml
<field name="cartype" type="lowercase" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="color" type="lowercase" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I want to delete "blue" and "stationwagon" tagged records from SOLR database with a curl command.

But I didn't do that with following command :

```sh
curl http://46.231.77.98:7979/solr/update/?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d "<delete>(cartype:stationwagon)AND(color:blue)</delete>"
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have to add `query` tag.

```xml
<delete><query>(cartype:stationwagon)AND(color:blue)</query></delete>
```

Comment: Is this equivalent to `+cartype:stationwagon +color:blue`?

Answer (score 7):

Using JSON instead of XML:

```sh
curl -g "http://localhost:8983/solr/$core/update" \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d '{"delete":{"query":"field:value"}}'
```

Answer (score 2):

In this way would be easier:

```
curl -g "http://localhost:8983/solr/collection/update" \
     -d '<delete><query>(cartype:stationwagon)AND(color:blue)</query></delete>'

curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/collection/update?commit=true"
```

It's a simple `POST` request.