# security threats in exposing solr query to customers in live website

Tags: solr, security

I am going to build a website and I am planning to use solr for search integration.It is a ecommerce web site. I wanted to know if there is any problem in exposing the solr query format to the users of this website?

Answer (score 3):

You want to have your search app query Solr, or use a proxy, so the URL is not exposed to the web user. I'm not so concerned about query syntax and parameters being visible, as long as the web user can't send them via query. You for certain want to make sure only the web app can reach the Solr server, however.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you lock down the RequestHandlers so that only searches are available through the web, there still may be things in your index that you don't want to expose to customers.

For example, if two items score the same in a search, you'd like to boost the one with the higher margin. In order to do that you need to have the margin in your index, and that means it's available for all of your customers and competitors to see.

The JSON response writer is very handy for writing lightweight search apps. At the very least you'll want to implement a filtering proxy between the browser and Solr.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely do not want to expose Solr directly to users. Nor do you want to pass the format through without evaluation.

One of the thing that Solr supports is [delete by query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719860/how-to-delete-solr-indexed-data-by-query-with-curl). There are other possibilities as well. You have to sanitize the content of queries.