# Is it possible to select and delete in the same query with SOLR (apache)

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

Documents can be added and removed any times.
I need to remove some documents for historic storage.

Is it possible to select AND delete in the same request ?

1. Select&delete data
2. Store data somewhere else.
3. Send commit.

Right now, I do :

1. Select data with criteria + stats=true&stats.field=dateField
2. Store data somewhere else.
3. Query delete (with same criteria but using the getMax() value of dateField to not delete newer documents matching the request)

Comment: Yeah, it's called "delete by query" 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719860/how-to-delete-solr-indexed-data-by-query-with-curl

Comment: I don't think so. deleteByQuery() return UpdateResult. There is no results/documents other than it is success or not.

Comment: hmm misunderstood your question, sorry about that. No I don't believe you can do a select + delete at once. The flow you're suggesting seems the right way to go.